# Javascript/jQuery: ensuring unique option added to pulldown

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have an HTML pulldown menu along with a text element that allows users to add new options to the menu. I'd like to make sure that every option that is added is unique. The following two lines were the first option I thought of that worked (option value = innHTML for all of the options). I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution to this -- the second line just seems clunky. It also doesn't handle spaces in the new_name string.

```
var new_name = document.getElementById("preset_name").value
var unique_name = $("option[value="+new_name+"]").length === 0 ? true : false
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using plain JavaScript and jQuery?

Comment: It looks OK. I'll bet the ternary is not needed. `unique_name = $("option[value="+new_name+"]").length === 0` should assign true or false by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

HTML:

```
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 
<input id="newoption" type="text" />
<button id="check">Check</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button#check").click(function() {
        var newOpt = $("input#newoption").val();
        $("#myselect option").each(function(){
            var text = $(this).val();
            if(newOpt.length>0 && text.indexOf(newOpt)!=-1){
                console.log("already present!");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bDZgh/4/)

Comment: Yes, that should work. I guess what I was wondering, though, if there's a very concise way to get the set of option values, for membership testing.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the two comments on the question, you could streamline down to 1 line:

```
var unique_name = $("option[value="+$("#preset_name").val()+"]").length === 0;
```

You don't need the ternary, as the === results in a true or false value.  Unless you need the test value again, you don't even need to store it in a variable - you can just retrieve it with jQuery.